# Account chooser and settings like google apps

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, material-you

I'd like to create an account chooser like recent google apps (gmaps like below picture, gmail, drive) for managing auth, and some user settings in my app.
I couldn't find any library or hint on how doing this, is anyone aware of somegthing that could help?

Otherwise, I think that is a DialogFragment with fully custom ui (Material You styled). Am I right?
Any help on finding a library, some examples or implementation/UI hint is well accepted!
It is better if available without compose, but I can use compose too.

Thank you!

[image: Account Chooser]

Comment: You can create a `Dialog` to get this